Reference Request - Social Choice Theory
I am looking for a mathematical introduction to the field of Social Choice Theory. In particular, I would like to understand the impossibility theorems of Condorcet and Arrow, as well as ways to circumvent the underlying issues. It would be great if the source also gives remarks on implications for trendy real-world voting systems.
So far the books I could find were mostly popular science, which is not what I'm looking for.
Any help is appreciated!

Ivar Ekeland "Elements d'économie mathématique", Hermann, 1979,  "Le théorème d'Arrow" from page 33.
Russian translation: Mir, 1983. Arrow Impossibility Theorem from page 31.

Fantastic, thank you!

I think this theorem is very important and would be happy to discuss it in more depth if/when you'll be agree.

I will get back to you, once I am more familiar with the matter.

I have now found "Social Choice theory: An Introduction" and "Arrow Impossibility Theorems" both by Jerry S. Kelly.
Any further references are of course still appreciated.

I strongly recommend that you start with Amartya Sen's "Collective Choice and Social Welfare". It explains the impossibility theorems of Condorcet and Arrow, and includes an extensive discussion on ways to relax the axioms to obtain possibility results. The main reason for reading this book is that it provides very good intuitive explanations for the results without compromising on the rigor.
Another resource that is helpful is the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy entry on social choice theory: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/social-choice/

Thank you for this suggestion!
